# Comparisons of template type passed in, to basetypes or objects

Tags: c++, templates, object

Is it possible to compare a template's type that was passed in to a function in the form of

```
/* Stuff prior to the function being called */
template <class BaseType>
void foo(BaseType bar){
    if(BaseType == 'Class made Object || some primitive Datatype')
    // This in hopes to make just one function that accepts, as a template, any argument
}
```

The `==` operator is not working, in the sense that it is meant to, and this is in C++ I know Java holds classes but not sure of anything past that, haven't started teaching myself that as of yet.
/***************************************************
Added from comment to expand on the given question.
***************************************************/
I'm pretty new to the concept of templates atm, I get how they work overall and understand how they are passed but want to be able to tell from within the function that is called with the template argument what is passed to it, as the question says, currently trying to get the BaseType be it an object created or if it's one of the primitive data types. It's convoluted but I want to see if its possible to do seperate points on the same function with different parameters being passed in, within the template. May add this comment to the main question as well, hopefully that isn't against SO regulations.

Comment: I think you need template specialization here but I'm rusty on that.

Comment: C++11 provides a long list of functions for working with types. Take a a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types.

Comment: I'm pretty new to the concept of templates atm, I get how they work overall and understand how they are passed but want to be able to tell from within the function that is called with the template argument what is passed to it, as the question says, currently trying to get the BaseType be it an object created or if it's one of the primitive data types. It's convoluted but I want to see if its possible to do seperate points on the same function with different parameters being passed in, within the template. May add this comment to the main question as well, hopefully that isn't against SO regs.

Comment: Under your point RSahu, should I attempt to view the point passed into the should the function is_object be used instead of attempting to delineate the BaseType that is passed into the given function, and branch off on that in itself, if that's the case it'll help for the current application, but is there a way to actually get the BAseType thats passed in, C++ must store it in some manner to be able to use it right? Such as calling the function and stating in <type> that is being passed to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
template <class BaseType>
void foo(BaseType bar){
    if ( std::is_class<BaseType>::value || std::is_fundamental<BaseType>::value )
    {
    }
}
```

However, depending on the problem you are trying to solve, template specialization might work as well or better.

Comment: I've just been introduced to template functionality, in the boo im currently reading, havent gotten to specialization yet. I'm jumping ahead a bit because it just seems as if it should be something that is doable, due to the calling of the functions that need the type being passed to it as in foo<int>(...) and such.

Comment: The subject of templates in C++ is interesting. You can keep it simple and straight forward. It can also be complex and confusing depending on  how you are using them. Hope you enjoy the journey.

Comment: Thank you, didn't think to approach it in the way you outlined initially, but the more you know right. Currently trying to follow through on the Practical C++ 2nd edt. by Oreilly to self teach a bit and stay ahead of the current class I'm in. This site in itself is beyond useful. Thnaks again for the link and subsequent example.